# Schedule the launch of a cordova app

Tags: cordova

Is it possible to have a cordova app start at a specific date and time, without any user interaction? Imagine for example a "wake up" app that would automatically start every morning and play your favorite radio station stream.

I've seen some local notification plugins like https://www.npmjs.com/package/de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification but it seems those kind of plugins are used to display a notification, and the app is only started/resumed if the user to tap the notification.

EDIT: I searched "radio wake up" on the stores and got lots of results, eg

- Android: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asicotrade.radioalarm&hl=en
- iOS: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/best-clock-radio-alarm-free/id858324439?mt=8

So it looks like it's possible, I'm just not sure what features they're using to achieve it.

Comment: I just have a feeling that Apple would not like that, or allow it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve that, that's why you don't see any app like that, only native android reminders can do that, like clock alarm.

Comment: I imagine it's not possible just through HTML, but a plugin should be able to add that feature, don't you think?

Comment: I think you can achieve this only if your app keep running on background all the time. Tha way you can manage what the app would do, send notification for example.
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

Answer (score 0):

I've customized  https://www.npmjs.com/package/de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification plugin to act as alarm.

have a look at https://github.com/vasani-arpit/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

Every syntax is same as [katzer's](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) plugin.

the difference is is app will wake up (come to foreground) every time notification is triggered.

Comment: so you modified the Android version of the plugin. You wrote the app will go from background to foreground, does it mean the app must be launched first?

Comment: yes, once the notification is scheduled, Notification will ring as well as app will also come to foreground.